# how does result = k + tri_recursion(k-1) give me an output of triangular numbers?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning about functions and I came across a recursions example on [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp). This code is giving me a list of triangular numbers for an argument k > 0. My question is how exactly is it printing out a list of triangular numbers with "result" defined as result = k + tri_recursion(k-1) in the body of the code. The output for an input of k = 6, for example, gives me 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21 but I just don't understand how I'm getting a list of triangular numbers from such a simple setting of the return variable. Help would be much appreciated :)

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    if k > 0:
        result = k + tri_recursion(k-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0 
    return result
print("\n\nexample result")
tri_recursion(6)
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Where is your execution trace?  Exactly where are you not understanding a particular line or two of code?  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource -- "teach me how this code works" -- with no exhibited effort -- is out of scope here.

Comment: I will try to improve the question after doing more research into functions and recursions; I am very new to the topic. To repeat my question, I was trying to understand how exactly result = k + tri_recursion(k-1) gives me an output of triangular numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need create a list to storage numbers:

```
tri_list = []
def tri_recursion(k):
    if k > 0:
        result = k + tri_recursion(k-1)
        tri_list.append(result)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0 
    return result
print("\n\nexample result")
tri_recursion(6)
print(tri_list)
```

Then you have:

```
k = 6
6 + tri_recursion(5)
      5 + tri_recursion(4)
             4 + tri_recursion(3)
                  3 + tri_recursion(2)
                       2 + tri_recursion(1)
                             1 + tri_recursion(0)
                             1 + 0 = 1
                        2 + 1 = 3
                  3 + 3 = 6
             4 + 6 = 10
        5 + 10 = 15
 6 + 15 = 21
```

This happens because you are printing the sum of the previous numbers in each return of each recursion

Comment: thank you, but what I am trying to understand is how exactly result = k + tri_recursion(k-1) gives me an output of triangular numbers.

Comment: Oh, okey! i changed my answer

Comment: this specific recursion is starting to make a lot of sense because of your answer, thanks for this visualization!